# Positioning ul under parent li

Tags: html, css

I have having problems getting the ul to sit underneth the li on the support button, any help getting this to play nicely would be appreciated.

```
<li>
     Support
     <span class="child-menu-arrow"></span>
     <ul class="child-menu">
          <li>Contact</li>
          <li>Other</li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5GpHZ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `margin`s on the child menu to push it in the direction you want. It is absolutely positioned, so it doesn't affect anything else to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/5GpHZ/5/

```
#parent-menu>li>ul.support-menu { margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px; }
```

By putting the adjustment on its own class, it will not affect the other submenus.

Comment: The problem with that is that it moves all of the sub-menus to those margins when the problem only occurs for the support menu.

Comment: @user3038885, you are going to have to apply a special hook onto just the support menu if this is the case, to target only that one and not the others. A `menu-support` class onto the `ul` and use that to fix only that one.

Comment: That could work but i don't really understand why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: @user3038885 it's happening because your `ul`, absolutely positioned but with no `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` values set, is being placed underneath the parent item in the document flow, but outside the document flow. So this is happening directly under the text on the support menu, and directly under the image in the other menu.

Comment: @JoshC do you have any reasoning for why it's not a good idea at all?

Comment: @setek Even if i take out the absolute positioning its still the support menu that is acting weird and the others function fine, any ideas: http://jsfiddle.net/nblackburn/5GpHZ/6?

Comment: @user3038885 if you check http://jsfiddle.net/5GpHZ/5/ it should be what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute;` and then set it where you want it. Notice that I changed your other menu to "child-menu2".

```
.child-menu{
position:absolute;
top:55px;
right:145px;    
}
```

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5GpHZ/8/)